# java GEF independ from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a project, we want the SWT/JFace GEF Eclipse plugin project independ from Eclipse IDE. for example, as a java project, we import the java libarary, and run the java application as normal, could anyone help me to give me an idea. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write an Eclipse `Rich Client Platform` (RCP), this includes enough of Eclipse to provide the infrastructure needed by all Eclipse plugins.

There are lots of web resources on writing Eclipse RCPs, see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) for example.

You cannot run Eclipse plugins in an ordinary Java program.